# Combine Multiple unrelated Select Statements using a flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, flags

My `Select` statements work fine individually. But can I have one `stored procedure` with all of them instead of having multiple procedures?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zPrintAll]
@PrintVariable varchar(10),
@SuppliedKey      varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@PrintVariable='ONE')
        BEGIN
            SELECT  *
            FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.key=Table2.key
            WHERE   Table2.key='@SuppliedKey'
        END
    IF(@PrintVariable='TWO')
        BEGIN
            SELECT  *
            FROM  Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.key=Table4.key
            WHERE   Table3.key='@SuppliedKey'
        END

END
```

EDIT: This is for a detailed print function. When I supply a PersonID, I go into each department and print their bill in that department. I will Print a main bill that has atleast 20 departments.
If My Print variable says 'Clothes', I would print the required fields from the 'Clothing department' for a PID. If My Print variable says 'Shoes', I would print the required fields from the 'Shoe department' for the PID and so on.
I have a crazy amount of procedures already and don't want to add another bunch of `Select` Statements in there.

I have done this for a Procedure that either 'Updates' or 'Deletes' based on a flag but it doesn't seem to be working here.

Comment: You "could", but I would not recommend it. Instead if you want such a structure - make each "IF" execute a specific stored procedure instead of just a statement.

Comment: if you want to kick yourself later - although taking the approach you suggest does create a certain amount of job security, especially as the product grows

Comment: I'm curious about the circumstances that led to this question being asked. Why are you considering this? What problem are you trying to solve? If you give us more information we may be able to suggest a better solution rather than comment on just this one idea.

Comment: I would need around 20+ procedures just for one print function, then. If My Print variable says 'Clothes', I would print the required fields  from the 'Clothing department' for a PID. If My Print variable says 'Shoes', I would print the required fields  from the 'Shoe department' for the PID.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw I have edited the question with the details you requested for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query but I got the syntax wrong when I replaced the static key with the variable.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zPrintAll]
@PrintVariable varchar(10),
@SuppliedKey      varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@PrintVariable='ONE')
        BEGIN
            SELECT  *
            FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.key=Table2.key
            WHERE   Table2.key=@SuppliedKey
        END
    IF(@PrintVariable='TWO')
        BEGIN
            SELECT  *
            FROM  Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.key=Table4.key
            WHERE   Table3.key=@SuppliedKey
        END
END
```

So, it is **`@SuppliedKey`** instead of **`'@SuppliedKey'`**

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zPrintAll]
@PrintVariable varchar(10),
@SuppliedKey      varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN
        SELECT  * 
        FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.key=Table2.key

        UNION ALL
        SELECT  *
        FROM  Table3 INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.key=Table4.key

        WHERE @SuppliedKey = CASE WHEN @PrintVariable='ONE' THEN Table2.key
         WHEN @PrintVariable='TWO' THEN Table3.key ELSE '' END 
    END

END
```

Comment: @Nagaraj, That is not really what I want. My select queries are complex and there are about ten of them. How Can I modify what I have?

Comment: @divinediu yeah then it is better to go with IF Else conditions and Flag Format then code will be clear and simple and more over it result set varies from each other..So better proceed as you posted your query

Comment: This approach could only ever work if the schema of table 1 joined to table 2, and table 3 joined to table 4 were identical (same number of columns of the same types). It is also, arguably, even more difficult to understand and maintain than the original suggestion.

Comment: @mohan111 It isn't working though. When I supply a PrintVariable and SuppliedKey, it doesn't work in the `if` blocks. It runs when I run it standalone with the same values. Why is that happening?

Comment: your query working fine may be the data type issue in input you are supplying varchar and in question you are saying clothingid and Shoeid so need to ID or just remove single quotes '@SuppliedKey'= @SuppliedKey